# Tradingview Pine Script how to check if day low price like 111 or 111.10 or 222 or 222.20 or 333.30 etc for any digit numbers

Tags: pine-script

How to identify if stock day low price format is like 111 or 111.10 or 222 or 222.20 or 333.30 etc (for any digit numbers) in tradingview pinescript .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script and look under the data panel to see how many digits is a min tick. If 0.1 you know its 200.1 if 0.01 then 200.11 and so on

```
plot(syminfo.mintick,title="Min Tick Value")
```

Comment: I want to label that price on chart if low price format is like 111 or 111.10 or 222 or 222.20 for any digit of numbers

Comment: I want all digits same  except last zero after decimal.